# React error boundaries for user authentication (with redux) -- why is local setState needed?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, redux, higher-order-functions

**Problem**

I'm trying to use [React error boundaries](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/960) to block content for non-logged in users.

I have a "working" solution, but I don't understand why my hack made it work Could someone help me unpick what I'm doing wrong?

### General theory of what I'm doing

*As I understand it...*

I have a component which sits in my app and wraps the main content block (not the main nav tho). It uses `componentDidCatch` to catch any `accessDenied` thrown and redirect the user to the login screen.

I have a HOC which any container can use to restrict itself to only logged in users. It checks the current state of `isAuthenticated` in the store and if redirects the user to the login page if they're not.

If you try to go to the restricted page, the HOC (`EnsureAuthenticatedConnector`) throws an error which bubbles up and is caught by `AuthBarrier`.

**So whats the problem?**

As the code is shown below this works. But I have a local state set on `AuthBarrier`. It does nothing.

If I remove  `this.setState({ hasError: true });`, it breaks.

The URL changes, the navbar renders (It's outside the error boundary), but the main screen is just white.

The login page never appears. What is `setState` doing, it isn't used?

### My code

**AuthBoundary.js -- Part 1 Auth checking function**

My HOC is expecting a component, however so is `connect` and both of them are functions ([ref](https://medium.com/practo-engineering/connected-higher-order-component-hoc-93ee63c91526)). To solve this we combine them with connect.

`EnsureAuthenticatedConnector` must come first (as we need it to have access to props, not the element its wrapping), so we have a double arrow function, so it gets access to both the component and props (that's the part I'm haziest on).

```
const accessDenied = {};

const EnsureAuthenticatedConnector = ComposedComponent => props => {
    if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
        console.log("This console fires twice, but only when an error is thrown in here.");
        throw accessDenied;
    }
    return <ComposedComponent {...props} />;
};

const mapStateToPropsEnsureAuth = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    };
};

const connectedEnsureAuth = compose(
    // These are both single-argument HOCs
    connect(
        mapStateToPropsEnsureAuth,
        null
    ),
    EnsureAuthenticatedConnector
);

...
export { ConnAuthBarrier, connectedEnsureAuth };
```

**AuthBoundary.js -- Part 2 Auth Catching element**

```
class AuthBarrier extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasError: false
        };
    }

    // Catch child errors if they're access denied.
    componentDidCatch(error) {
        if (error === accessDenied) {
            // For reasons unknown removing this line
            // causes this to break.
            // This makes no sense, because I don't use this anywhere...
            this.setState({ hasError: true });
            this.props.dispatch(push("/login"));
        }
    }
    render() {
        // We do nothing clever always render the 
        // children
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
const ConnAuthBarrier = connect()(AuthBarrier);
```

**RestrictedPage.js**

```
import { connectedEnsureAuth} from "components/AuthBoundary";

const RestrictedPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This content is TOP SECRET</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

RestrictedPage.displayName = "RestrictedPage";

const AuthRestrictedPage = connectedEnsureAuth(RestrictedPage);

export default AuthRestrictedPage;
```

**Full console log of errors**

Console log when rendering completely. 
[image]

When `setState` remove then the following line also triggers:
`Warning: AuthBarrier: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.`

**Relevant modules**

- "react": "^16.7.0",
- "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
- "react-router": "^4.3.1",
- "connected-react-router": "^6.2.2",

Answer (score 2):

Error boundaries were introduced for one and only purpose: so that the app doesn't break when an error is thrown, right?

From the docs:

> A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines either (or both) of the lifecycle methods `static getDerivedStateFromError()` or `componentDidCatch()`. Use `static getDerivedStateFromError()` to render a fallback UI after an error has been thrown. Use `componentDidCatch()` to log error information.

So the idea is simple:
`getDerivedStateFromError` is a static function that returns a state update.

Why? Because if you don't update your state after an error is encountered, there is no way to tell if the render method of the error boundary knows **"it is time to render some fallback UI"**. Again, the purpose of error boundary is to deal with the error thrown. So when there is no update of state, there is no way of knowing the error boundary properly did it's job. So the error propagates.

> If an error boundary fails trying to render the error message, the error will propagate to the closest error boundary above it.

In you example, you are not using `getDerivedStateFromError`, rather `componentDidCatch`. In that function you may have sent the user to another page (which is *your way* of dealing with the error). But unless you set the state manually (which should have been done with `getDerivedStateFromError`) there is no way to tell that your error boundary **"has dealt with this error, it shouldn't go any upper**".

And we know what happens when the error propagates and there is no one to deal with it:

> As of React 16, errors that were not caught by any error boundary will result in unmounting of the whole React component tree.

That is why your "main screen is just white".

Hope this helps. [Docs on Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Comment: why do we need to set state inside `static getDerivedStateFromError`? I can also set state inside `componentDidCatch` and after that, I can render a Fallback component.

Comment: You could do [that](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010) as well. The question was about **why** state change is important, not where.

Comment: Yeah, I know what the question was. Actually, React recommends that setting state should be done in `static getDerivedStateFromError` and `componentDidCatch` should only log errors as in future you can't set state inside it.